# Global variable set to null after first test Execution Testng Thread Local WebDriver Object

Tags: selenium, testng, thread-local

Hi all i have two classes like below i can able to run sequentially without any problem but if i run this sample two test cases parallely in second test method the objects are setting to null.for some reason i used thread-local varaiblesPlease find my code in below.In browsersetup class iam creating driver instance

```
public class SeleniumMethodsClass {
    private  static ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>();
    private static ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> logger = new ThreadLocal<ExtentTest>();
    private static ThreadLocal<ExtentReports>  report= new ThreadLocal<ExtentReports>();
    private static int time=20;

    public  static  RemoteWebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver.get();
    }

    public  static void setDriver(RemoteWebDriver setdriver) {
        driver.set(setdriver);
    }

    public static ExtentTest getLogger() {
        return logger.get();
    }

    public static void setlogger(ExtentTest setlogger) {
        logger.set(setlogger);
    }

    public static ExtentReports getreport() {
        return report.get();
    }

    public static void setreport(ExtentReports setlogger) {
        report.set(setlogger);
    }

    public  static void initilization(String testCaseDescription) throws Exception{
        RemoteWebDriver driver=BrowserSetup.createdriverInstance();
        String url=JsonReader.readJson("envconfig","ApplicationUrl");
        SeleniumMethods.setDriver(driver);
        driver.get(url);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        ExtentReports report=ReportTemplate.instance();
        SeleniumMethods.setreport(report);
        ExtentTest logger=ReportTemplate.loggerinstance(testCaseDescription);
        SeleniumMethods.setlogger(logger);
    }
}
```

`ClassOne` and `ClassTwo` look like below :

```
public class ClassOne {
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws Exception{  
        SeleniumMethods.initilization("Producer_CRUDIndividualNo");
    }

    @Test
    public void create_producer() {
        try{
            //Some test code
        } catch(Exception e){
            //Exception handling
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void create_producer2() {
        try{
            //Some test code
        } catch(Exception e){
            //Exception handling
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tear_down(){
        ReportTemplate.close_intialization();
    }
}
```

TestNG suite xml file looks like below :

```
<suite name="ProducerPro_Automation" verbose="2" parallel="classes" thread-count="5">   
    <test name="Producer HealthCheck1" verbose="2">
        <classes>  
            <class name="class1"/>
            <class name="class2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Could you please help me on this.I have lot of test scripts based on this framework, i do not want to modify in script level.Please suggest me.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your
 question. Great questions tend to generate quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: In addition, please format your code correctly. Nobody wants to debug code that is hard to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue could be due to the fact that you are initialising your `ThreadLocal` variables from within a `@BeforeClass` annotated method. TestNG does not guarantee you that all your `@Test` methods and `@BeforeClass` methods will run in the same thread. 
Since your initialising your `ThreadLocal` variables in a different thread and trying to access them in a different thread, you are perhaps seeing `null` values.

This doesn't happen when you run sequentially because there are no concurrent executions.

To fix this problem you have a couple of choices :

- Annotate your `setUp()` method with a `@BeforeMethod` instead of using `@BeforeClass`
- Move your `SeleniumMethods.initilization("Producer_CRUDIndividualNo");` invocation into a listener that implements `IInvokedMethodListener`, inside a `beforeInvocation()`. This will be technically equivalent to doing it from within a `@BeforeMethod` method, but you don't have to go and change this in every class, and it helps keep your class clean.

You can read more about Listeners in general in [this](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/listen-to-what-i-have-to-say-about-testng-listeners/) blog post of mine, and also refer to [this](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/) blogpost to learn how to use the notion of listeners to instantiate and cleanup webdrivers.

Comment: Thanks krishnan for your answer.I implemented threadlocal concept by reading your blog only.